# IPython (Spyder) is very slow and often freezes running on Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, ipython, spyder

I've just changed from MATLAB to Python and I'm rather disappointed.

I've installed Spyder 2.3 for Python 2.7 via terminal on my early '15 MBP (just for you to get an idea about the hardware) with OS X El Capitan installed on it and the IPython console it is pretty slow.

Running simple commands like numpy's `np.arange()` or sometimes even while calculating fundamental things just as `1+1`, it takes between several seconds and a minute and sometimes it even freezes for a couple of minutes.

Since I'm trying this now for a week (writing codes itself is not a problem, it's just about running commands in IPython) and I didn't find a solution, I'd like to ask you for a possible reason. Of course I restarted the machine during this time and the memory isn't running out of capacity.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't know about Spyder, but what if you run `ipython` directly from Terminal.app? IPython freezes are at least unheard of for me.

Comment: Interestingly, running IPython from the terminal works fine. Although I would prefer to use an IDE I would try it that way then. Thank you so far.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) @8kmk, sorry to hear that Spyder is not working for you as expected in El Capitan. We have received several other reports telling us about similar problems in that OS X version. Unfortunately, I think all these problems are related to the graphical toolkit used by Spyder (Qt4). We're working to update it to its next version (Qt5) in a couple of months.