# IPython console in spyder extremely slow in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, spyder

I'm trying Anaconda/Spyder after using the standard python installation/IDLE for several years. The console (and variable explorer) becomes progressively slower during each work session, with every script and interactive command that I run. Eventually it takes minutes to get a response to simple commands like print, and then it stops responding completely and I shut it down. It's pretty disruptive to my work.

Mac OSX 10.13.6

```
conda version : 4.5.11
conda-build version : 3.15.1
python version : 3.7.0.final.0

qt 5.9.6
spyder 3.3.1 
ipython 7.1.1
```

I do use matplotlib frequently. Whenever possible I use plt.ioff() at the beginning of a script and/or plt.close('all') at the end. Turning off matplotlib support completely in preferences doesn't help and it's not a permanent fix anyway. Python is not using anywhere near all my CPU or RAM.

Comment: I recently started having the same problem, with virtually the same setup. I haven't had any luck with a solution yet but I did find this open issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2902#event-1898390735

Comment: It's really unusable. What are you using in the meantime?

Comment: Yeah, it is, I have actually been spending most of my time trying to figure out how to fix it rather than getting anything done. Still no luck. I have found this, which may be describing the same issue as well with a response from a dev that it may have to do with Qt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860095/ipython-spyder-is-very-slow-and-often-freezes-running-on-mac-os-x-10-11 That being said I have not found another IDE that is appealing enough for me to try but if I can't get this figured out I may have to jump ship.

Comment: For me, Spyder just has too many problems to be usable, especially problems involving Qt. As soon as there is a good interactive Python shell on VS Code (which will be soon) I will switch completely.

Comment: I don't think I would agree with 'too many problems to be usable'. This is the first problem I have really had with it (over many years of basically daily usage across many platforms and updates) and as far as scientific/data analysis programming goes it really stands out as high quality.

Comment: @JJR4 unfortunately that response from the spyder dev is from 2015. Not sure where they are these days.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I just want to mention that we're pretty much baffled by this problem. We really don't know where it's coming from (it could be Python 3.7, IPython 7+, or ipykernel 5+). If you have some free time to help us to narrow down the exact conditions that generate it, at least we could inform that to the Jupyter guys so they can take a look at it.

Comment: Also, please post that info to the issue you are participating in Spyder's Github website.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, Is there an open issue for this problem on github?  I'm available to help test/reproduce this issue, as it has become a major impediment for me.

Comment: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is not a totally satisfying solution but it seems to be a reasonable temporary fix. If you downgrade your spyder version to 3.1.X you will be able to use the python console rather than the Ipython console, and this seems to work for me. To do this just run:

```
conda install spyder=3.1
```

in the terminal while your environment of choice is active. This is not ideal, because the developers removed the python console for a specific reason as mentioned in this question, [How to add python console in spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960590/how-to-add-python-console-in-spyder). 
Additionally downgrading this much may have unforeseen effects on other packages your code uses and may cause other issues but so far this is the only solution I was able to come up with.

Comment: I use Spyder 3.3.1 and it runs very well. The ipython console is very quick and the script runner is fast. Spyder seems to be an excellent Python ide.  I am in no way responsible for the Spyder App, just a satisfied customer.

Comment: @JJR4 Yeah this is working for me so far. Another issue, though, is that I don't seem to have the variable explorer in the python console--is that a feature or a bug?

Comment: @andbeonetraveler That's odd, I do have the variable explorer and it seems to be working properly for me. Is it not there at all or not working? If you go to View >> Panes >> Variable Explorer you should be able to toggle it on and off, you may need a restart to see the effect. If you have nothing displayed in the variable explorer you can try the refresh button in the upper left hand corner of variable explorer pane.

Comment: @JJR4 refresh did it, thanks! I guess it's just not auto-refreshing for some reason.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I've found out, the problem seems to be with the latest major release of the ipython kernel. Pinning the version of ipykernel to 4.10.0 solved it for me. To do so, add a line containing `ipykernel 4.*` to the file `~/anaconda3/conda-meta/pinned`. Create the file if it does not exist yet. Then `conda update ipykernel` which will actually downgrade to 4.10.0. Worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

you don't need to downgrade the entire spyder.
For me it worked with downgrading these two:

`conda install ipython=6.4.0
conda install ipykernel=4.10.0`

Comment: I only downgraded ipykernal to 4.10.0 and left ipython where it was at 7.2.0.  And it worked.  So happy about this!!!

Answer (score 3):

@Sjoerd Thanks for your answer, this is what worked for me. To be still clearer, here's what I did in terminal on Anaconda 3 on High Sierra:

> echo "ipykernel 4.10.0" >> ~/anaconda3/conda-meta/pinned
>
> conda update anaconda

When I tried to update only ipykernel, I would have dependencies errors. By updating anaconda, everything is now up to date but ipykernel which is effectively at version 4.10.0. I didn't experience any hang since then.

Comment: Fantastic, this solved my problem. I had to update conda, and only then downgrade ipykernel, though (the opposite order).

Answer (score 0):

@JJR4's answer didn't work for me (seems to work for others). Another workaround is to type `%connect_info` magic command into the IPython Spyder console which will display the JSON info to connect another console to the kernel.

The output of the magic command explains how to connect, but basically there are three options.

Paste the above JSON into a file, and connect with:

```
$> jupyter <app> --existing <file>
```

or, if you are local, you can connect with just:

```
$> jupyter <app> --existing <kernel>.json
```

or even just:

```
$> jupyter <app> --existing
```

if this is the most recent Jupyter kernel you have started.

I typically use qtconsole as the app. Once you enter your chosen connection method into the command line, a new console will open that is connected to the same kernel as the console in Spyder. For some reason, the new console does not lag even if the Spyder console does.

Enter everything in the new console, even `runfile()`

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:
Downgrading to ipykernel version 4.10 seems to solve the issue for me. Thanks to Carlos Cordoba - see GitHub conversation in link below.

Comment: Are you also using macOS?

Comment: Yes, I'm on macOS 10.12.6

Comment: Ok, please post your versions of ipykernel, IPython and jupyter_client [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2902) to see if we can narrow down this problem.

Comment: Posted as cgit2017. Hope you can figure it out. Thanks for all your hard work.