# How to downgrade Ipykernel to ver. 4.10

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, spyder

I'm  completely new to programming in Python, so I i've got no idea how to  do this.

I'm using SPYDER, and the IPython console is PAINFULLY slow after running only a few lines of code. I'm on OSX.

I've read that downgrading my ipykernel to version 4.10 should work, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Writing "conda install ipykernel=4.10"

in the console or in terminal, doesn't do anything.
Step by step - what should I do?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it correctly. Maybe you could elaborate on what "*doesn't do anything*" means? Usually, the best approach is to copy exactly what you've entered into your shell and exactly what the output was - it's much less ambiguous than prose.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381373/ipython-console-in-spyder-extremely-slow-in-anaconda